# Uniqueness in coordinate transformation

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the coordinate transformation from the cartisian $(x,y)$ system to a $(r, \theta)$ coordinate system by $x=r \cos \theta $ and $y=r \sin \theta$, does it immidiately follow $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\geq 0$ or do we have to mention the definability region of $r$ and $\theta$ clearly as we've done done in $(x,y)$ system as $-\infty<x,y<\infty$?

Can we say the coordinate transformation $x=r \cos \theta $ and $y=r \sin \theta$ is a unique one (polar)?

The doubt come accros with an integration $$\int\int_D |f(x,y)| dxdy,~f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}& (x,y) \neq (0,0)\\0&(x,y)=(0,0)\end{array}\right.,~D=[-1,1] \times [-1,1],$$
in a presentation. The speaker made a transformation $x=r \cos \theta $ and $y=r \sin \theta$ and commited
$$\int\int_D |f(x,y)| dxdy=\int_{-1}^1\int_0^{2\pi} |f(x,y)| rd\theta dr,$$ to conclude that it is not integrable. It seems to me not correct.

Comment: The conversion to polar coordinates is unique, as long as the following three rules are followed.  [1] $r$ must be a positive number. [2] The angle $\theta$ is considered within a modulus of $2\pi$.  For example, the number $(x=1,y=1)$ could be converted to either $~\displaystyle \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \pi/4\right)~$ or $~\displaystyle \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 9\pi/4\right).~$ [3] $x = 0, y = 0$ is excluded from the conversion.

Comment: Re my last comment, an intuitive argument of uniqueness is that for any $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$, the (**positive**) scalar $r$ can be used to normalize the number.  That is $(x,y)$ conversion has form $(r,\theta)$ if and only if $~\displaystyle \left(\frac{x}{r}, \frac{y}{r}\right)~$ is some point on the unit circle.  Further, for each point $(x_1, y_1)$ that is on the unit circle, there exists (within a modulus of $2\pi$) a unique $\theta$ such that $x_1 = \cos(\theta), y_1 = \sin(\theta).$  ...see next comment.

Comment: An easy way to see this is to let $\theta$  move through the range $0 \leq \theta < 2\pi.$  For each such $\theta$, consider the ray going from $(0,0)$ to some point on the unit circle, such that the angle formed by this ray, and the line $\overline{(0,0), (1,0)}$ is $\theta$.  As $\theta$ increases (i.e. moves through the range $0 \leq \theta < 2\pi$) the corresponding ray will intersect each point on the unit circle exactly once.

Comment: Re last comment, I revealed my Analytical Geometry roots.  If you consider $\theta$ to simply be some real number such that $0 \leq \theta < 2\pi$, an argument analogous to the previous comment can be made by considering (on the unit circle) the arc length of size $\theta$.  Each point $(x_1, y_1)$ on the unit circle will be uniquely represented (within a modulus of $2\pi$), by a specific arc length.